# Are subgradients bounded on compact subsets of an open set?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-geometry, variational-analysis, subgradient

**Context & Motivation**: This is a preliminary question that I wanted to answer in order to generalize the nonconvex projected gradient descent method in Chapter 3 of the book [Non-convex Optimization for Machine Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.07897.pdf) to the nonsmooth case. Specifically, I wanted to know if the classic subgradient could be analyzed in the nonconvex setting using the same principles in the convex case, i.e., by looking at the size of the subgradients of the objective function in the nonconvex setting.

**Question**: Let $\Omega \subseteq {\mathbb R}^n$ be a possibly nonconvex open set, and suppose $X$ is a compact subset of the interior of $\Omega$, i.e., $X\subseteq {\rm int}\ \Omega$. Moreover, let $f:\Omega \mapsto {\mathbb R}$ be such that for every $x\in\Omega$ there exists an open ball $\cal B$ around $x$ such that $f$ is convex on $\cal B$.

Does there exist a constant $L > 0$ such that $\|v\| \leq L$ for every $v\in\partial f(x)$ and $x\in X$ (where $\partial f(x)$ is the convex subdifferential of $f$ at $x$)? In other words, are the subdifferentials of $f$ uniformly bounded when restricted to a compact subset?

Comment: Prove the claim on the balls $\mathcal B$, cover $K$ by such balls, then the claim follows by compactness

Comment: Thanks! From your hint, the (slightly) more detailed argument seems to be as follows: (1) assign the "right" ball to each $x \in X$, (2) $f$ is locally Lipschitz for each ball and hence $\partial f$ is bounded in each ball, (2) since the balls cover $X$ and $X$ is compact, there is a finite subcover, (4) the desired constant $L$ is just the largest bound of $\partial f$ over the balls in the finite subcover.

Comment: What is variational about this?

Comment: Since $\Omega$ is nonconvex, I wasn't sure if we needed any of the machinery from variational analysis. Should I remove the tag now that I know the solution follows from basic principles in convex analysis?

Answer (score 1):

**Too long for a comment.**

Here is the *idea of the proof.*

Suppose $\varphi$ a convex locally lipschitzian function that has a closed support hyperplane (which by definition, is a continuous linear form). Given a unit vector $u,$ and $x$ a centre of the ball, you can restrict the function $\varphi$ on the line segment inside this ball that passess through $x$ in direction $u.$ $\varphi$ restricted to this line segment is a convex function from an interval to the reals, which therefore has lateral derivatives (a.k.a. side derivatives), both of which are non-decreasing. Since $\varphi$ is lipschitzian, these lateral derivatives are bounded by the lipchitzian control-constant, *a fortiori*, the bounds are independent of $u.$ In *finite dimensions*, your hyperplane is necessarily given as a row matrix, this will show that all entries in this row matrix are bounded by constants independent of $u$ and therefore, the associated linear transformation will also have bounded movement (i.e. the support hyperplane can only tilt a little on every direction). QED

Comment: There are a few details that are unclear to me here: 

(1) What is the relation between $\varphi$ and $f$? Certainly, we cannot have $f=\varphi$ as $f$ here is only defined on the nonconvex set $\Omega$.

(2) The "lipschitzian control-constant" may be independent of $u$, but it may not be independent of $x$. Does your argument somehow imply that $\partial f(x)$ is uniformly bounded on $X$ without requiring $X$ to be compact?

Comment: The argument ought to show that if $f$ is defined on a ball, convex and $\lambda$-lipschitz there, then the directional side-derivatives of $f$ exists and are bounded (in absolute value) by $\lambda.$ If $X$ is compact, cover it by $k$ balls, and then the directional side derivatives of $f$ will be bounded everywhere  by $\max(|\lambda_1|,\ldots,|\lambda_k|).$ Or so the idea goes.